# Dynamically changing background color

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, background, brush

In my Windows Phone 7 app, I want `ContentPanel`'s background to change its color within a specified time (3 seconds in this case). Basically I want it to be "**flashing**".

But the problem is that the changes do not appear while the loop is working, the color changes only once, after the loop is done working. Why?

```
byte R;
TimeSpan ts = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3);
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();           
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime();    

requirement = true;
while (requirement)
{ 
    R = Convert.ToByte(0.5 * 255 * (1 + Math.Sin(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)));
    ContentPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, R, 125, 70));
    dt1 = DateTime.Now;
    dt2 = DateTime.Now;
    dt2.Subtract(dt1);
    if (dt2.Subtract(ts).CompareTo(dt1) > 0) requirement = false;
 }
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: Try adding a call to `thread.sleep()` in between getting `dt1` and `dt2`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your loop is too tight.

Try this instead:

```
private DispatcherTimer _timer;

private void StartFlash()
{
  _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
  _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
  _timer.Tick += (s,e) => ChangeColour;
}

private void StopFlash()
{
  _timer = null;
}

private void ChangeColour() {
  // Your colour changing logic goes here
  ContentPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(a,r,g,b));
}
```

Put that code in a class. Call StartFlash() somewhere. ChangeColour will execute every second.

Comment: This solution does not work either. Thank you for effort though.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for DateTime.Now way too fast so the difference will equate to 0 as DateTime's accuracy does not go as far as nanoseconds (Dates are marked by **milliseconds** from the unix epoch after all).

You might want to limit the while with more solid logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to do in async way.

The UI is not updated during your method execution, moreover if you work in the UI thread.